# AWS SDK3 not working inside the Web-worker

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-worker, aws-sdk-js

I am using AWS SDK3 to upload files to AWS S3. Its working fine from my React Component but not working from the webworker as the JDK code not getting complied for the web-worker.

Below is my code.

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: REGION,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
    }
});

const uploadParams = {
    Delimiter: "/",
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `test/${directory}/` + remainingFiles[i].name,
    Body: blob
};
try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
    console.log(data);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is web-worker? Also "but not working" is not specific. Why exactly it does not work? What are error messages?

Comment: Web-worker a very common JavaScript feature.

Comment: In my case it's working fine but getting issue like window not defined while uploading large files.